# FileStash support in Kubuntu 19.10

Tags: kubuntu, dolphin, 19.10

I am talking about https://kde.org/applications/system/org.kde.filestash.

But I couldn't make the icon visible in dolphin. How can I enable it ? What packages should be installed ?

Comment: See this [reddit link](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/dm3gld/filestash_icon_not_visible_on_dolphin_in_kubuntu/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x). If true, that's a pity.

Comment: same here (Kubuntu 20.04) ... why is it that support for such nice features are dropped but remain in the UI?